# How to add authentication to GuzzleHTTP Request Objects for asynchronous processing

Tags: php, authentication, guzzle

I am creating multiple of the following GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Requests:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$myRequest = new Request(
    'GET',
    $someUri
);
```

And save them in an array: $guzzleRequests

I then create a pool to simultaneously execute all requests:

```
    use GuzzleHttp\Pool;

    $testPool = new Pool($testClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(), $guzzlePromises,
    [
        'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
            // this is delivered each successful response
            var_dump($response);
        },
        'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
            // this is delivered each failed request
            var_dump($reason);
        }
    ]);
    // Initiate the transfers and create a promise
    $promise = $testPool->promise();

    // Force the pool of requests to complete.
    $promise->wait();
```

(Taken from the Doc: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html under "Concurrent requests")

This works for requests to URIs that don't need authentication and returns a 200 OK Status.

How do I add authentication to the Request so that the Pool can run multiple requests against Basic HTTP Authorization protected APIs at the same time?

### *edit 1:

In response to [pinkal vansia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31053244/2144292):
I added the header as you suggested:

```
$headers = [
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($this->username.':'.$this->password),
];
$myRequest = new Request(
    'GET',
    $url,
    $headers
);`
```

and dumped the headers:

```
array (size=2)
    'Host' => 
    array (size=1)
        0 => string '<myHost>' (length=27)
0 => 
    array (size=1)
        0 => string 'Authorization: Basic <veryLongAuthenticationString>' (length=<stringLength>)`
```

The response still yields unauthorized:

```
private 'reasonPhrase' => string 'Unauthorized' (length=12)
private 'statusCode' => int 401
```

### * final edit:

I finally got it running. It turns out, [pinkal vansia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31053244/2144292) was already pretty close.

The exact form was the last problem. [Michael Downling's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052003/how-to-add-authentication-to-guzzlehttp-request-objects-for-asynchronous-process?noredirect=1#comment50264536_31052003) comment brought me on the right track.

The Authorization header is the way to go and it needs to be a key => value mapping.

The final thing looks like this:

```
$url = $myUrl.'?'.http_build_query($this->queryArray);

// ------------ Specify Authorization => key to make it work!!!
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Basic '. base64_encode($this->username.':'.$this->password)
];
// -----------------------------------------------------------

$myRequest = new Request(
    'GET',
    $url,
    $headers
);

return $myRequest;
```

Comment: What kind of authentication do you need to add?

Comment: Basic HTTP Authentication, using a password and a username. Originally I would have done it using $request = client::get()->setAuth(). Before sending the request out: $request->send(). So if you are used to the old syntax, that is what I want to rebuild using the new syntax.

Comment: Here, originally we had that:
  return $this->guzzleClient->createRequest('GET', $url, [
    'auth'  => [$this->username, $this->password],
    'query' => $this->queryArray
  ]);
This does not exist anymore. We need to re-create it in the new way of doing it.

Comment: Headers are a hash of header name to value. Don't specify the headers as a line in a single string but rather a key mapping to a value.

Comment: @MichaelDowling your comment did show me the way in the end, after another hour of fiddling with it. Fixing this problem took me over 2 days to get to the bottom of it and even more time fixing it now. Since it was simply a formal problem, providing a **single** example of the right form would have saved me hours of work. You would have been able to provide this easily. I understand you are a busy person and I am a beginner, but please may I ask you to make it easier for the next beginner, asking a stupid question, trying to learn the framework you are coding.

Comment: "You would have been able to provide this easily" Do you mean in the docs or in my comment? It is documented pretty thoroughly (along with examples) at http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#headers and http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#auth

Comment: I disagree. The documentation lists many examples of authentication using Client::get() and many examples how to reacte a Psr7\Request, with headers as well. But not one with an authenticated Request. Now I am not saying smarter people than me wouldn't have figured it out faster. I am also not saying that everything should be spoon-fed to everyone. It would have just saved me so much time and nerve for such a simple problem. I was basically asking "how do you spell 'ham' and all I could get was 'look for pig and go from there'". Hopefully this topic makes it easier for others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add Basic Authentication header in Request as below

```
$headers = [
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($this->username.':'.$this->password)
];

$myRequest = new Request(
    'GET',
    $url,
    $headers
);
```

I hope this Helps.

**UPDATE**

As @worps pointed out `header` needs to be a `key => value` pair. so final solution is like below,

```
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Basic '. base64_encode($this->username.':'.$this->password)
];

$myRequest = new Request(
    'GET',
     $url,
     $headers
);
```

Comment: I edited my original question. Comments didn't allow for proper formatting.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have changed the creation of request.Please try it.

Comment: I have Edited my Answer. Now i am setting 'header' in options array as per https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php

Comment: This returns a Promise instead of a Request, leading the Pool to respond with "Each value yielded by the iterator must be a Psr7\Http\Message\RequestInterface or a callable that returns a promise that fulfills with a Psr7\Message\Http\ResponseInterface object." in line 61 of GuzzleHttp\Pool.

Comment: Your solution was almost perfect. I added the "final edit" to my question. It includes the correct form. Would you update your answer accordingly, so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help and examples! Really helped me. Marked answer. Cheers!